# Объекты в документе расположены не на одной линии

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не могу понять, почему блоки не на одной линии. "Лорэмы" по количеству слов одинаковые, картинки специально задал одним размером... Ничего не даёт, и псевдокласс вообще непонятно себя ведёт.
Почему такое поведение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.our-work {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3,
.section4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px;
}

.section1:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #f1eee9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section2:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #f1eee9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section3:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #f1eee9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.our-work img {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.our-work span {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #555555;
}

.our-work p {
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<section class="work-block">
  <div class="our-work">
    <div class="section1">
      <img src="img/icon1.png" alt=""><br>
      <span>Web & App Design</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section2">
      <img src="img/icon2.png" alt=""><br>
      <span>Development</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="section3">
      <img src="img/icon3.png" alt=""><br>
      <span>Customization</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p><br><span class="bor"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="section4">
      <img src="img/icon4.png" alt=""><br>
      <span>Marketing</span>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: не на одной линии, потому что название вкладки занимает не одну, а две строчки

Comment: @Дмытрык, не совсем понял,можете перефразировать?

Comment: первый заголовок имеет две строки и потому перенеслось

Comment: @UbuntuUser, это на скриншоте так, оно на одной линии.
Ладно ,хорошо, допустим из-за переноса а другие 3 из-за чего?

Comment: ну вот смотри https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OaRjxr

Comment: @UbuntuUser, это из-за картинок,я картинки убрал и стало всё на один уровень...
Им тогда разрешение задать или как?
Чтобы они не толкали элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В блоке `section3` после параграфа есть `<br/>`
2. И как сказали выше `<span>` для `section1` занимает две строки.

Решить можно таким способом:

```css
.work-block {
 width: 800px;
}

.our-work {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: space-between;
}

.section1,
.section2,
.section3,
.section4 {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 25px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.section1:after {
 display: block;
 content: "";
 height: 4px;
 width: 40%;
 background-color: #f1eee9;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.section2:after {
 display: block;
 content: "";
 height: 4px;
 width: 40%;
 background-color: #f1eee9;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.section3:after {
 display: block;
 content: "";
 height: 4px;
 width: 40%;
 background-color: #f1eee9;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.our-work img {
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.our-work span {
 font-size: 1.4em;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #555555;
}

.our-work p {
 color: #555555;
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<section class="work-block">
    <div class="our-work">
        <div class="section1">
            <img src="img/icon1.png" alt=""><br>
            <span>Web & App Design</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section2">
            <img src="img/icon2.png" alt=""><br>
            <span>Development</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="section3">
            <img src="img/icon3.png" alt=""><br>
            <span>Customization</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p><span class="bor"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="section4">
            <img src="img/icon4.png" alt=""><br>
            <span>Marketing</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus deleniti commodi quasi ipsum voluptatum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Точно,моя невнимательность...
Но все же я убрал и они все равно не стоят в одной плоскости.
1 и 3 блок ниже идут чем 2 и 4. и даже 1 и 3 не в одной линии, блоки идентичны,все были копированы, колиличество текста одинаково везде.

Comment: Тоесть Вы сократили строку "Web & App Design" до одной линии, убрали `<br/>` и 1, 2, 3 по прежнему не в одной линии?

Comment: Насчет 4 элемента ("Marketing") там нет псевдоэлемента, поэтому оно не выравнивается со всеми

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/PGkjFJZ.png

Comment: Это из-за картинок,я картинки убрал и стало всё на один уровень...
Им тогда разрешение задать или как?
Чтобы они не толкали элементы?

Comment: да, картинкам нужно задать размеры

Comment: Благодарю за ответы)

Answer (score 0):

Все эти попытки решить проблему на чистом css тут скорее всего провалятся. Заголовки блоков в будущем могут поменяться, как и содержимое их блоков .section.

Если нужно сделать, чтобы было красиво на всех разрешениях, лучше написать скрипт, который будет при загрузке страницы(или по какому-то другому событию, например по разрешению экрана) перебирать все нужные блоки (span с заголовком и .secton) и задавать им всем высоту, равную высоте самого высокого из блоков. Когда эти блоки встанут в одну колонку (на мобильниках), этот скрипт можно не включать.

Скрипт можно использовать, например, такой...

```
$.fn.equivalent = function (){
var $blocks = $(this),
    maxH    = $blocks.eq(0).height();

$blocks.each(function(){

    maxH = ( $(this).height() > maxH ) ? $(this).height() : maxH;
});

$blocks.height(maxH);
}

$('.same-height-class').equivalent(); //Общий для блоков, у которых должна быть одинаковая высота, селектор.
```

То есть всем заголовкам нужно задать какой нибудь класс, и указать его здесь. Затем продублировать последнюю строку и указать в ней селектор для всех текстов под заголовками. И все должно выровняться.

Comment: Вы серьезно полагаете что данная проблема не решается на CSS и что запуск скрипта который будет перерисовывать DOM в цикле при загрузке страницы это хорошее решение? Просили передать привет от "оптимизации скорости загрузки".

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach Да, полагаю. Потому что с помощью CSS решается именно ДАННАЯ проблема. Вот только проблема эта к суровой реальности никакого отношения не имеет. Пока у нас lorem вместо текста. Но потом этот сайт обрастет контентом. Заголовки могут поменять, тексты поменяют точно. И всё выравнивание сдохнет ещё раз. А скрипт это довольно мелкий. И работает он с очень просто отрисовываемым свойством - высотой. Так что скорость загрузки особо не испортит.

Comment: Можно пример суровой реальности? Только такой чтобы я точно не смог решить с CSS. а насчет "мелкого скрипта" почитайте про [recalculating style](https://github.com/vasanthk/browser-rendering-optimization/blob/master/README.md) и про [евенты которые его вызывают](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a)

Comment: @Alexandr Tovmach. Пожалуйста. Оставляем этот же код, но слегка меняем вводные. И заголовки и тексты у нас теперь выводятся из админки. А вносит их туда либо менеджер проекта, либо сам заказчик. Задача: Сделать 4 блока в ряд, в каждом из которых содержится изображение, заголовок, текст и линия друг под другом. Изображения должны быть выровнены по верхам с изображениями, заголовки с заголовками, тексты с текстами, линии с линиями. Подвох в том, что у одного из блоков заголовок в 3 строчки, у другого в одну. +- то же самое с текстами. Блоки при адаптиве выстраиваются в колонку.

Comment: Дал себе вольность немного подправить CSS для Вашего решения, потому что Вы не предоставили, а без него не работает: 
https://codepen.io/alexandrtovmach/pen/vVRMrY . Так как это наша личная дискуссия то я не буду публиковать это как ответ и оставлю это в виде ссылки (простив правил stackoverflow)